# How can I obtain the bleed box size of a PDF page?

Tags: itext

I'm trying to get all possible page boundaries from a PDF, but when I ask for the "bleed", I get a Null value:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string source = @"C:\\Users\\numx\\Desktop\\TestPDF.pdf";
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);

        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle cropBox = reader.GetCropBox(1);
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle mediaBox = reader.GetBoxSize(1, "media");
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle trimBox = reader.GetBoxSize(1, "trim");          
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle artBox = reader.GetBoxSize(1, "art");

        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle bleedBox = reader.GetBoxSize(1, "bleed");

        MessageBox.Show(bleedBox.ToString());
        reader.Close();

    }
```

Comment: The value `bleedBox` is `null` because the document doesn't have a bleed box. Show us the PDF so that we can prove this allegation.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, what i'v realize that bleedbox object isn't create until modify it with pitstop... the default value is same as cropbox (=Null in itext)

Comment: Do i have to open new post to ask ( detect Null bleedbox ) not rising error

Comment: No need to open a new post; you can adapt your current question. However, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. There are trillions of PDFs who don't have a `/BleedBox`. Why would this have to raise an error? If you want to throw an exception for such a PDF, just check for `null` and throw that error.

Comment: I'm gone loop through thousand PDF, Reporting every boxSize of every Pages and C# raise an error when bleedbox is Null... I suppose that the catch error isn't Itext library matter... but C# programming

Comment: Indeed, it's not an iText problem. This causes an exception: `bleedBox.ToString()` because `bleedBox` is `null`. That's not iText's problem; that is just bad coding (it's the type of error a teacher marks as an error resulting in a lower grade). You should check if `bleedBox` is not `null` before using any method on that object.

Comment: I know that Bruno, at the time that i was posting my code, i didn't anticipate a Null return ( because all other boxe's returning numbers ) Thanks

Comment: OK, I made an answer so that people see that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recap what we discussed in the comments.

When you do this:

```
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle bleedBox = reader.GetBoxSize(1, "bleed");
```

Then `bleedBox` is an instance of the `Rectangle` class when the PDF defines a bleed box; when no bleed box is defined, `bleedBox` is `Null`. In the latter case, you will get an exception when you invoke the `ToString()` method on it.

So, if you need the `bleedBox`, first check if `bleedBox` is `Null`. If it's not, work with the `bleedBox` object. If it isn't, use the crop box instead. If there's no crop box, use the media box.

Of all the page boundaries, only the media box is mandatory. All the other types of page boundaries are optional.